# Why can i not cast a class to the same type of class | java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.comphenix.tinyprotocol.TinyProtocol$PacketInterceptor cannot be cast to
com.comphenix.tinyprotocol.TinyProtocol$PacketInterceptor
```

Can someone tell me why this Error comes up altough it should not?

Comment: Can you also add the code causing this issue?

Comment: sounds like the class is loaded by 2 different ClassLoaders